# Save document inside document or Object id inside document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How is better to save one document inside one document, save all the document or save the objectID and find all the objectsID that i need?. For example.

```
> Collection A  { "_id": ObjectId("4f67da1538fc5d7347000000"),
> Name:'name', "products": {
>        "0": {
>          "barcode": "25001",
>          "name": "GoldClass",
>          "Price": "12.00",
>          "CashBack": "2.00" 
>       },
>        "1": {
>          "barcode": "25002",
>          "name": "Weekday",
>          "Price": "12.00",
>          "CashBack": "2.00" 
>       },
>        "2": {
>          "barcode": "25003",
>          "name": "Weekend",
>          "Price": "24.00",
>          "CashBack": "4.00" 
>       }  }}
```

O save the ObjectID of product that i want to save and if a need to show the products do a query to find one by one these products?

Comment: It depends on many aspects, if you want to reuse or search products list it is better to store them in separate collection. But if you only have few, unique products you can embed them.

Comment: I will do operations with only a field of the products (quantity) but it will be a masive edit operation...and add new products and delete products..

Comment: You can take products as an array too.